# How to run python script on clicking button?

Tags: python, button, callback, plotly, plotly-dash

**Goal:** I have never done this before, and am new to python. I want to run a python script on call as a button is pushed.

**Question**: Can someone give pointers as to how to go about solving this?

**My Code**:

```
**Button HTML**
    # Layout of Dash App HTML
    app.layout = html.Div(
        children=[
            html.Div(
                            html.Button('Detect', id='button'),
                            html.Div(id='output-container-button',
                            children='Hit the button to update.')
                         ],
                    ),
                ],
            )

@app.callback(
    dash.dependencies.Output('output-container-button', 'children'),
    [dash.dependencies.Input('button')])
def run_script_onClick():
    return os.system('python /Users/ME/Desktop/DSP_Frontend/Pipeline/Pipeline_Dynamic.py')
```

**Currently this gives the error:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "app.py", line 592, in <module>
    [dash.dependencies.Input('button')])
TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'component_property'
```

EDIT:

I think the solution might be to add some_argument to the run_script_onClick:

```
def run_script_onClick(some_argument):
        return os.system('python /Users/ME/Desktop/DSP_Frontend/Pipeline/Pipeline_Dynamic.py')
```

I am currently browsing through [this](https://dash.plot.ly/dash-html-components/button) list to find an appropriate item() to use as argument.

Comment: What do you understand from that error message? Have you tried fixing that first?

Comment: HI @AMC, it mentions that I am missing another argument for the function I am trying to call. (So something like function(arg1, arg2). Currently it considers 'button' but perhaps another argument that is correlated to the return (the script that should run) ? But I don't know how to go about that exactly. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: _Currently it considers 'button' but perhaps another argument that is correlated to the return (the script that should run) ?_ I'm not sure I understand what you mean. This might be of use: https://dash.plot.ly/dash-core-components/input.

Comment: @AMC yes I used that link to get where I am now. But I am a bit stuck and am wondering what argument I am missing to make the return python script run upon click.

Comment: Have you tried adding the second argument to `Item()` like they have on that page?

Comment: @AMC Could you please check my post-edit? Perhaps it is not the second argument, because I see that my run_script_onClick() is empty and currently does not have an argument. Perhaps adding a argument for URL?

Comment: What is that code meant to do?

Comment: @AMC The intend is that if I click on the button ('run_script_onClick()) on the webpage, it should run the pipeline_dynamics.py code (which is a script I wrote to update the current CSV with newly incoming data and append that to the existing script).

Comment: That really isn't the best way of executing Python code in another file/program, though. Can't you use that script like you would any other library?

Comment: @AMC so by importing that script and calling assigning one of its primary functions to the button instead? I haven't done that before either, sounds scary. But if that is a better way, I suppose I can try it.

Comment: _so by importing that script and calling assigning one of its primary functions to the button instead? I haven't done that before either, sounds scary._ You might not have done that before with that particular script, or any script you wrote, but you do have a bunch of imports at the top of this program, and those haven't caused your computer to explode, right? ;)

Comment: While that is a good improvement to make, it's unlikely to fix the current error. Have you seen [this page](https://dash.plot.ly/dash-html-components/button), by the way?

Comment: @AMC no haven't seen that page yet. I'll go through it perhaps it shall enlighten me. And otherwise I'll try to import the script into my current code and just call a function upon some time-interval condition. Thanks for the help so far ;)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206198/discussion-between-amc-and-user7186746).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's what I would use:

```
from subprocess import call
from dash.exceptions import PreventUpdate

@app.callback(
    dash.dependencies.Output('output-container-button', 'children'),
    [dash.dependencies.Input('button', 'n_clicks')])
def run_script_onClick(n_clicks):
    # Don't run unless the button has been pressed...
    if not n_clicks:
        raise PreventUpdate

    script_path = 'python /Users/ME/Desktop/DSP_Frontend/Pipeline/Pipeline_Dynamic.py'
    # The output of a script is always done through a file dump.
    # Let's just say this call dumps some data into an `output_file`
    call(["python3", script_path])

    # Load your output file with "some code"
    output_content = some_loading_function('output file')

    # Now return.
    return output_content
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried what you said. It outputs the following message: '
TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'component_property'
Here are the available properties in "button":
['children', 'id', 'n_clicks', 'n_clicks_timestamp', 'key', 'role', 'data-*', 'aria-*', 'autoFocus', 'disabled', 'form', 'formAction', 'formEncType', 'formMethod', 'formNoValidate', 'formTarget', 'name', 'type', 'value', 'accessKey', 'className', 'contentEditable', 'contextMenu', 'dir', 'draggable', 'hidden', 'lang', 'spellCheck', 'style', 'tabIndex', 'title', 'loading_state']'

Comment: aah now I get n_clicks better. This clears up a lot. Thanks for that. I'll look more into the 'some_loading_function' part, in order to grasp it better for my case. That file I am trying to run checks whether there has been any new data from sensors. If so, it appends the new data to the existing csv. That is was 'pipeline_dynamic.py' does. So many there is no need for '   output_content = some_loading_function('output file.csv')' as long as the file runs in the background.

Comment: Is there a way to check if the file ran successfully. Now I have commented output_content and return output_content. I have added: print('file loaded successfully). But is there a function that actually check if that file ran successfully or not?

Comment: 2 options for you @user7186746 – 1) place a print statement at the end of your  `pipeline_dynamic.py` file or 2) manually inspect the outcome file

Answer (score 1):

@ Yaakov Bressler. This works for me without using the following lines. Thanks a lot.

```
output_content = some_loading_function('output file')
    return output_content
```